# How get all values from NSMutableDictionary for key?

Tags: xcode, get, key, nsmutabledictionary

How I get all values from `NSMutableDictionary`, but only for `key @"Column1"` or how get index row for key?
I try `[dict objectForKey: @"Column1"];` , but I get only last value for `key (user3)`.

example table:

```
Column1 --  Column2

user1   --  20
user2   --  30
user3   --  50
```

Comment: what is Column1 and Column2? is column1 key and column2 object ??

Comment: I solved it Column1 and Column2 are keys and rows are array. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the answer yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use fast enumeration:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *thisDict in array) {
    NSLog(@"Result for Column1 is %@", [thisDict objectForKey:@"Column1"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Result is

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++){
   NSLog(@"Result for Column1 is %@", [[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Column1"]);
}
```

Comment: Fast Enumeration (see my answer) is much more efficient at iterating over objects than objectAtIndex methods.